# link_to helper giving me ?id= instead of / (slash)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this in my routes.rb:

```
resources :profiles, :only => :show
```

I'm building a link like this: `<%= link_to( "profile", profile_path(13)) %>` and it's giving me a url of `/profile?id=13` - I want it to give me `/profiles/13` (as that one works).

What am I doing wrong?

Rake routes result for this resource:

```
GET      /profiles/:id(.:format)                                     profiles#show
```

Comment: What is `rake routes` returning?

Comment: You could always replace this with `get 'profiles/:id', to: 'profile#show', as: 'profile'`

Comment: Yeah, I have a workaround in place to do that, but I want to know why!  I'll update the post to include what rake routes returns.

Comment: rake routes looks fine. Could it simply be `profiles_show_path` instead of `profile_path`?

Comment: Just for a try, what happens if you use this: `resources :profiles, except: [:index, :edit, :create, :destroy, :update]`?

Comment: Gives the same result with ?id=

Comment: If you manually set the param do you get the same behavior?  `<%= link_to( "profile", profile_path(id: 13)) %>`

Comment: Same kind of goofy ?id= link .
I can put another one of my resources right next to my profiles resources in routes and it will behave how I'd expect (/model/13), but profiles just doesn't.  Maybe it's something bizarre with my model.